# Angular i18n Dynamic text

Tags: javascript, angular, internationalization, ngx-translate, angular-i18n

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to change language for a dynamic content using i18n and related libraries like (ngx-translate) for which I am doing a POC.

I am able to translate the static content but I am not able to figure out how to do the same for dynamic content, like,  content in ngfor loop or data coming from the server.

Is there any way to do the conversion for content coming from the backend/db?

or any other advice/suggestions would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Any content that matches a key in your translation files would do. So if your backend gives you such keys, you can just use translate:

```html
<div *ngFor="let key of keys">
  <p translate>{{key}}</p>
</div>
```

Or something like that. If this is what you meant?

Comment: this is a better, cleaner answer

Comment: Same difference Sam, your has prefixes, which may help the OP. :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is fairly simple, provided you know the values your backend may deliver:

```
// backend data returns known possible values:
const values = ['red', 'blue', 'green']

// de.json
color: {
  "red": "Rot",
  "blue": "Blau",
  "green": "Grün"
}

// app.component.html

<div *ngFor="let value of values">
{{ ('color.' + value) | translate }}
</div>
```

Comment: This is nice because of the 'color.'-prefix. Combined we could do <span translate>color.{{value}}>

Comment: If I know already know the value, then it is easy.. but what if I dont know what the backend is returning?

like google translate it automatically translates everything to the nearest possible translation

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not how ngx-translate works, you must provide the key:value pairs as a json file ahead of time. As a solution for your needs you could potentially write a service that passes your backend value to another translation service (for example https://www.deepl.com/en/docs-api/) which would return the translated value.